# How to get the html code from webview without usinh jsoup?

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I want to get the html code from webview and then put it in textview.
Someone suggested me to use jsoup but in my case jsoup doesnt work because my target site have login page.

Example only
Getting the html code from

https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/1185861891542944?refid=27

If I used jsoup It wont get the html from the url above because jsoup cant logun fb.

Im asking for your help on how  to get the html code from webview and then put it in textview?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, you can use jsoup to authenticate and fetch the data from web applications. Take a look at [this](https://riptutorial.com/jsoup/example/16273/a-more-comprehensive-authentication-post-request-with-jsoup) tutorial.